# Can testdisk change physical geometry?

Tags: hard-disk, testdisk

I don't actually want to do it because I am paranoid, but my question is: can I actually change my drive physical geometry using `testdisk` and damage a drive to the point of being unrecoverable?  Does testdisk support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the physical geometry of a disk. Hard disks don't have any “physical geometry” that can be changed in software. Hard disks don't even report any physical geometry information to the computer — things like cylinders are a software abstraction that hasn't been related to the hardware since the late 1980s.